# How do I change the directory of InMemoryUploadedFile?

Tags: python, django

It seems that if I do not create a ModelForm from a model, and create a new object and save it, it will not respect the field's upload directory.

How do I change the directory of a InMemoryUploadedFile so I can manually implement the upload dir? Because the InMemoryUploadedFile obj is just the filename, and I would like to add the upload dir parameters. Thank you!

```
def add_image(self, image):
    pi = ProductImages()
    pi.image = image
    pi.save()
    self.o_gallery_images.add(pi)
    return True
```

(Code that does not respect the upload dir of ProductImages "image" field)

Comment: So what is the argument 'image' -- an in-memory image, a file name, something else? If it is a file name, then maybe your ProductImage.save() should copy the file to the new directory if it is not already there. Similarly for an in-memory image.

Answer (score 1):

How did you define the attribute of image in your ProductImages model? Did you have upload_to argument in your FileField?

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
```